# My Android app freeze the Mobile System UI

Tags: android, exception, android-anr-dialog

Going through the problem from the last few weeks but still, can't find a solution. Searched a lot on internet but all in vain because such issues are hard to describe when you don't know which part of the code is creating a problem.

**Once in a while, my app freezes the mobile UI especially when the app is in the background** and I want to clear the recent apps opened. Now the real problem is I am not able to track the root cause of the problem.

My app total code size is around 1 Gb, and APK **size is 6MB** is that creating a problem?

**I got the following exception in the case of ANR:**

```
E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.android.systemui
    PID: 18257
    Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting to send non-key event because the touched window has not finished processing certain input events that were delivered to it over 500.0ms ago.  Wait queue length: 1.  Wait queue head age: 24768.7ms.)
    Load: 13.74 / 21.07 / 24.51
    CPU usage from 0ms to 5389ms later:
    107% 992/system_server: 80% user + 26% kernel / faults: 16718 minor 383 major
    13% 18956/com.android.phone: 6.3% user + 7.4% kernel / faults: 4036 minor 578 major
    0.1% 279/debuggerd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 3654 minor 74 major
    8% 18257/com.android.systemui: 3.7% user + 4.2% kernel / faults: 2492 minor 618 major
    6.9% 2167/com.motorola.process.system: 3.5% user + 3.3% kernel / faults: 2822 minor 53 major
    3.9% 18939/com.motorola.modemservice: 2% user + 1.8% kernel / faults: 1870 minor 362 major
    3.7% 18275/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 2% user + 1.6% kernel / faults: 1493 minor 22 major
    0% 2184/com.qualcomm.services.location: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2034 minor 209 major
    2.4% 3821/adbd: 0.3% user + 2% kernel
    1.8% 149/mmcqd/0: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
    0.2% 157/ueventd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
    0.2% 256/logd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 34 minor 1 major
    0.2% 22787/logcat: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
    0.9% 3594/mpdecision: 0% user + 0.9% kernel / faults: 1 major
    0.9% 26489/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 0.9% kernel
    0.5% 2037/kworker/0:2: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
    0.1% 3/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
    0% 8/migration/0: 0% user + 0% kernel
    0% 138/cfinteractive: 0% user + 0% kernel
    0.1% 1214/RX_Thread: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
    0% 1219/wpa_supplicant: 0% user + 0% kernel
    +0% 23000/migration/1: 0% user + 0% kernel
    +0% 23001/kworker/1:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
    +0% 23002/kworker/1:0H: 0% user + 0% kernel
    +0% 23003/ksoftirqd/1: 0% user + 0% kernel
    +0% 23004/kworker/1:1: 0% user + 0% kernel
    68% TOTAL: 40% user + 24% kernel + 3.1% iowait + 0.3% softirq
    CPU usage from 4613ms to 5148ms later with 99% awake:
    64% 992/system_server: 50% user + 14% kernel / faults: 1067 minor 3 major
    55% 1371/InputDispatcher: 48% user + 7.4% kernel
    5.5% 1163/ActivityManager: 0% user + 5.5% kernel
    1.8% 1153/SensorService: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
    1% 1214/RX_Thread: 0% user + 1% kernel
    1% 2037/kworker/0:2: 0% user + 1% kernel
    1.8% 3821/adbd: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
    1.8% 3821/adbd: 0% user + 1.8% kernel
    1.1% 18275/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 1.1% user + 0% kernel
    1.3% 22787/logcat: 0% user + 1.3% kernel
    32% TOTAL: 23% user + 9.2% kernel
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ...we can´t know without any further information...

Comment: try adding some code and explain why your app takes 1gb of space

Comment: it is freeze because are you doing too much data process on main thread move heavy lifting task in separate thread and it will work.

Comment: app working fine but it gives problem while clearing it from memory i.e recent apps.Could anybody tell me why it freezes only when 
I clear recent apps, I am surprised by this behavior?

Comment: But why it is freezing once in a while if there is load on main thread, it should give ANR everytime.

Comment: too much heavy work going on

Comment: When I clear phone Ram, sometime a pop up appears "System ui stopped working" and phone freezes up for sometime...really annoying...don't know whats wrong with the code.